# Bus Error, don't know what to do

Tags: c, bus-error

I'm writing a program for an assignment I have at school to model the oscillations of a coupled harmonic oscillator (a block connected to a wall by a spring, and another block connected to the first block by a spring). With this my extension I have chosen is to model n blocks connected by n springs! Up to a reasonable amount, I started by trying 3.

When I attempt to compile it it compiles fine and I can run the program for the first part which only requires input. After that it just crashes, giving a bus error. Here is my code, sorry it might seem like a wall!! It begins by taking a number of values from the command like for the positions of the blocks.

```
#include    <stdlib.h>
#include    <stdio.h>
#include    <math.h>

/* Set variables for the width of the blocks and rest length of the springs*/
#define     w   1.0
#define     R   1.0

/*Define our external function for finding the runge kutta constants*/
double rkutta(double *xpos, double *omeg, double *j,  int delta, int n, int N);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
FILE*   output;
int     tmp, N;
double  *x, *v, *m, *k, *omega, mtmp, ktmp, t, dt, *xstep, *vstep;

/*Find value of number of masses from the command line*/
N = argc - 1;
dt = 0.001;

/*Allocate array memory for each variable required*/
x = malloc(N*sizeof(double));
v = malloc(N*sizeof(double));
m = malloc(N*sizeof(double));
k = malloc(N*sizeof(double));
omega = malloc((2*N - 1)*sizeof(double));

/*Read values for the x position of each mass from command line*/
if(x != NULL && v != NULL && m != NULL && k != NULL && omega !=NULL)
{
    for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
    {
        sscanf(argv[tmp+1], "%lf", &x[tmp]);
    }
}
else
{
    printf("***************************\n");
    printf("**Error allocating arrays**\n");
    printf("***************************\n");
}

/*Check there are an appropriate amount of masses,
if so take values for other quantities from user*/
if(N <= 1)
{
    printf("************************************\n");
    printf("**There must be at least 2 masses!**\n");
    printf("************************************\n");
}
else if(N == 2)
{
    for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
    {
        printf("Input a value for the velocity of Block %d\n", tmp+1);
        scanf("%lf", &v[tmp]);
    }

    for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
    {
        printf("Input a value for the mass of Block %d\n", tmp+1);
        scanf("%lf", &m[tmp]);
    }

    for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
    {
        printf("Input a value for the spring constant of Spring %d\n", tmp+1);
        scanf("%lf", &k[tmp]);
    }
}
else
{
    for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
    {
        printf("Input a value for the velocity of Mass %d\n", tmp+1);
        scanf("%lf", &v[tmp]);
    }

    printf("Input a value for the mass of each Block\n");
    scanf("%lf", &mtmp);
    for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
    {   
        m[tmp] = mtmp;
    }

    printf("Input a value for the spring constant of each Spring\n");
    scanf("%lf", &ktmp);
    for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
    {
        k[tmp] = ktmp;
    }   
}   

/*Compute values of each omega*/
for(tmp=0; tmp<(2*N-1); tmp++)
{
    if(tmp % 2)
    {
        omega[tmp] = k[(tmp+1)/2] / m[(tmp-1)/2];
    }
    else
    {
        omega[tmp] = k[tmp/2] / m[tmp/2];
    }
}

/*Define arrays for runge kutta constants*/
double      *a, *b, *c, *d;

/*Calculate the values of the runge kutta constants*/
for(tmp=0; tmp<(2*N); tmp++)
{
    if(tmp < N)
    {
        a[tmp] = v[tmp];
    }
    else
    {
        a[tmp] = rkutta(x, omega, 0, 0, (tmp-N), N);
    }
}
for(tmp=0; tmp<(2*N); tmp++)
{
    if(tmp < N)
    {
        b[tmp] = v[tmp] + 0.5*dt*a[tmp+2];
    }
    else
    {
        b[tmp] = rkutta(x, omega, a, (0.5*dt), (tmp-N), N);
    }
}
for(tmp=0; tmp<(2*N); tmp++)
{
    if(tmp < N)
    {
        c[tmp] = v[tmp] + 0.5*dt*b[tmp+2];
    }
    else
    {
        c[tmp] = rkutta(x, omega, b, (0.5*dt), (tmp-N), N);
    }
}
for(tmp=0; tmp<(2*N); tmp++)
{
    if(tmp < N)
    {
        d[tmp] = v[tmp] + dt*c[tmp+2];
    }
    else
    {
        d[tmp] = rkutta(x, omega, c, dt, (tmp-N), N);
    }
}

/*Open file to output data*/
output = fopen("1209937_proj1.out", "w");

for(t=0; t<=0.1; t=t+dt)
{

    if(output != (FILE*)NULL)
    {
        fprintf(output, "%lf ", t);
        for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
        {
            fprintf(output, "%lf ", x[tmp]);
        }
        for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
        {
            if(tmp<N-1)
            {
                fprintf(output, "%lf ", v[tmp]);
            }
            else
            {
                fprintf(output, "%lf\n", v[tmp]);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("*********************************\n");
        printf("**Error outputting data to file**\n");
        printf("*********************************\n");
        return(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    /*Use runge kutta to find the next value of v and x*/
    for(tmp=0; tmp<N; tmp++)
    {
        xstep[tmp] = x[tmp] + (dt/6)*(a[tmp]+2*b[tmp]+2*c[tmp]+d[tmp]);

        vstep[tmp] = v[tmp] + (dt/6)*(a[tmp+2]+2*b[tmp+2]);
        vstep[tmp] = vstep[tmp] + (dt/6)*(2*c[tmp+2]+d[tmp+2]);

        x[tmp] = xstep[tmp];
        v[tmp] = vstep[tmp];
    }
}

free(x);
free(v);
free(m);
free(k);
free(omega);
fclose(output); 
return(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

/*Given various quantities find runge kutta values*/
double rkutta(double *xpos, double *omeg, double *j,  int delta, int n, int N)
{
int     temp;
double  result;

result = 0;

for(temp=0; temp<N; temp++)
{
    xpos[temp] = xpos[temp] + delta*j[temp];
}

if(n=0)
{
    result = -omeg[n]*(xpos[n]-R) + omeg[n+1]*(xpos[n+1]-xpos[n]-w-R);
}
else if(n < N-1)
{
    result = -omeg[2*n]*(xpos[n]-xpos[n-1]-w-R); 
    result = result + omeg[(2*n+1)]*(xpos[n+1]-xpos[n]-w-R);
}
else
{
    result = -omeg[(2*n-1)]*(xpos[n]-xpos[n-1]-w-R);
}

return(result);
}
```

I haven't really done much programming so I'm sorry if it's something obvious. I just want to fix it. The program runs up until after all the data has been put in by the user.

Comment: A bus error generally means you're accessing memory incorrectly, for example by dereferencing an uninitialized pointer. Single-stepping in the debugger should help you track down the error point.

Comment: Umm I'm not really sure what you mean. What debugger? And how would i go about single stepping the code?

Comment: Which compiler/OS are you using?

Comment: gcc through my school, i connect to their server through putty

Comment: The debugging tool with gcc is called `gdb`.  You run it like: `gdb a.out` (or whatever your program is called).  Make sure you use a `-g` when compiling so that you have debugging information in your program file.

Comment: Do we really want to use Stack Overflow as a homework service? These kind of problems are easy to solve if one takes the time to learn something, which is not achieved by this method...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running in the debugger it fails here for me:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000400cfb in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffe508) at t.c:116
116             a[tmp] = v[tmp];
```

Looking at `a` we find that its un-initialized.

```
(gdb) p a
$1 = (double *) 0xc2
```

Looking at your program, we see that you define:

```
/*Define arrays for runge kutta constants*/
double      *a, *b, *c, *d;
```

But you have not defined an array, you've defined an empty pointer and not set it to anything.

Change this to

```
double a[100], b[100], c[100], d[100] ;
```

And then the compiler will create memory for those (at least for N up to 50).

Comment: Okay thank you i see what i've done. Thanks for showing me the debug tool as well! I ahve no real clue how to use it at the moment but i can learn!

Comment: Gah, i changed it, now i'm getting a segmentation fault :S

Comment: There are more problems, after changing those, there are still segfaults.

Comment: Yer noticed the problem with `xstep and vstep` was the same, changed that. Still a segfault

Comment: Okay i've solved the problem, i was sending an integer as a pointer to the external function. Thanks for showing me gdb, very useful!